# How to get rid of the original file path instead of name in PGP encryption with ChoPGP library?

Tags: encryption, bouncycastle, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

I tried PGP encrypting a file in **ChoPGP** library. At the end of the process it shows embedded **file name** along with the whole **original file name path**.

But I thought it will show only the filename without the whole path. Which I intend to work on and figure out a way to do so?

Doing the following:

```
            using (ChoPGPEncryptDecrypt pgp = new ChoPGPEncryptDecrypt())
        {
            pgp.EncryptFile(@"\\appdevtest\c$\appstest\Transporter\test\Test.txt",
                @"\\appdevtest\c$\appstest\Transporter\test\OSCTestFile_ChoPGP.gpg",
                @"\\appdevtest\c$\appstest\Transporter\pgpKey\PublicKey\atorres\atorres_publicKey.asc", 
                true, 
                true);
        }
```

- **which will result in:**

[image]

- But I would like to only extract the Test.txt in the end something
  like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this line from the ChoPGP sources: https://github.com/Cinchoo/ChoPGP/blob/7152c7385022823013324408e84cb7e25d33c3e7/ChoPGP/ChoPGPEncryptDecrypt.cs#L221

You may find out that it uses internal function `GetFileName`, which ends up with this for the FileStream: `return ((FileStream)stream).Name;`.

And this one, according to documentation, `Gets the absolute path of the file opened in the FileStream.`.

So you should either make fork of ChoPGP and modify this line to extract just filename, or submit a pull request to the ChoPGP. Btw, it's just a wrapper around the BouncyCastle so you may use that instead.